# Connect database in Clean architecture dot Net 7?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to know where to give database connectivity configuration in clean architecture dot net 7 project? I created 3 layers and Asp.net web api project in dot net 7.Ususally i will
write connection string in appsettings.json file and will do the CORS and database configuration in program.cs file .Then will create one class file for dbcontext and call that context class file in controller to get the data from database.But in this clean architecture the logic is written in AuthorRepository class file under AuthorInfrastructure layer  to get the list and all written in .Now my doubt is how to call the db context in AuthorRepository file to get the data from database.For sample i hardcode the list.Please clear my doubts.Thanks

**Layers**

**1)Author.Domain
2)Author.Application
3)Author. Infrastructure**

[image]

**Author Domain Layer**

In Author domain layer i created **AuthorViewModel** class

[image]

**AuthorViewModel**

```
public class AuthorViewModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column("UID")]
    public int AuthorUID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String AuthorFirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String AuthorLastName { get; set; }
    public int PublisherID { get; set; }
}
```

**Author Application Layer**

In application layer i created one class and two interface

**1)AuthorService
2)IAuthorRepository
3)IAuthorService**

[image]

**1)AuthorRepository**

```
 public interface IAuthorRepository
  {
    List<Domain.AuthorViewModel> GetAllAuthor();
  }
```

**2)IAuthorService**

```
   public interface IAuthorService
    {
       List<Domain.AuthorViewModel> GetAllAuthor();
    }
```

**3)AuthorService**

```
   public  class AuthorService : IAuthorService
   {
    private readonly IAuthorRepository authorRepository;
    public AuthorService(IAuthorRepository authorRepository)
    {
        this.authorRepository = authorRepository;
    }
    List<Domain.AuthorViewModel> IAuthorService.GetAllAuthor()
    {
        return this.authorRepository.GetAllAuthor();
    }
}
```

**Author Infrastructure Layer**

[image]

I created AuthorRepository class in AuthorInfrastructure layer

**AuthorRepositiry**

```
  public class AuthorRepository : IAuthorRepository
  {
    public static List<Domain.AuthorViewModel> lstAuthor = new List<Domain.AuthorViewModel>()
    {
       new Domain.AuthorViewModel{  AuthorUID =1 ,AuthorFirstName= "Kirtesh Shah", AuthorLastName ="G"  },
       new Domain.AuthorViewModel{  AuthorUID =2 ,AuthorFirstName= "Mahesh Shah", AuthorLastName ="S" },
       new Domain.AuthorViewModel{  AuthorUID =3 ,AuthorFirstName= "Nitya Shah", AuthorLastName ="G" },
       new Domain.AuthorViewModel{  AuthorUID =4 ,AuthorFirstName= "Dilip Shah", AuthorLastName ="S" },
       new Domain.AuthorViewModel{  AuthorUID =5 ,AuthorFirstName= "Hansa Shah", AuthorLastName ="S" },
       new Domain.AuthorViewModel{  AuthorUID =6 ,AuthorFirstName= "Mita Shah", AuthorLastName ="G" }
    };
    public List<Domain.AuthorViewModel> GetAllAuthor()
    {
        return lstAuthor;
    }
}
```

Finally api controller

**AuthorController**

[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthorController : ControllerBase
{

```
    private readonly IAuthorService authorService;

    public AuthorController(IAuthorService authorService)
    {
        this.authorService = authorService;
    }
    // GET: api/<MembersController>
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IList<AuthorViewModel>> Get()
    {
        return Ok(this.authorService.GetAllAuthor());
    }

}
```

Comment: How to get the DBContext into the repository is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/). Prseumably you use DI so explicitly look at the part describing the injection of the DBContext. From where you get the needed data to create the DBContext is then up to you. I don't have a preference there. Do whatever fits best to the way you host your App. If thats still the appsettings.json then use that.

Comment: if i create db context file in Models then how i can call that in AuthorRepository file ? can you pls give any idea

Comment: Pardon? Do you use Dependency injection? Then that is the place to configure something like a DBContext for example and use injection into the Repository (the DBContext is then an injected parameter in the Repositories constructor).

Comment: @Ralf My doubt is In AuthorRepository i hardcoded some author list .Instead of hardcoding i want to get the list from database so my doubt is  in authorRepository how to call the db connection ?

Comment: You get it via the DBContext that has been injected into the Repository as described in the link i provided in first comment. But i noticed you switched wording from db context to db connection. If you simply struggle with connection to a database ignoring all the surrounding stuff of ASP.Net, depedency injection and so on just a pure how to use a database that would belong in its own independent question.

Answer (score 1):

In your IoC layer, add:

```
    services.AddDbContext<yourDbContextName>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
);
```

of for Lazy Loading:

```
    services.AddDbContext<yourDbContextName>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")).UseLazyLoadingProxies()
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully not necro-ing, was looking for an answer for the exact same problem and this is what ended up doing.

In dependency injection point,

```
public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration databaseConfiguration)
{
  var cs = databaseConfiguration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
  services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(cs));
}
```

from the entry point program or startup class, the call looks like

```
builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);
```